# How do I keep the status of content during the navigation?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a `Frame` in `MainPage`, and there's content in `MainPage`, for example, a `List` which is dynamically generated by a function (let's call it `loadList()`) which is invoked by the `Loaded` event of `MainPage`.

After user clics on any items in the `List`, The `Frame` could be navigated to another page (lets call this `DetailPage`). Every time I navigate back to the `MainPage` from `DetailPage`, the `MainPage` invokes the `Loaded` event, therefore invokes the `loadList()` again.

My question is, that, is there any way I can keep the status of the content and keep it from being generated again once it is generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default in UWP pages are unloaded when the user navigates from them. This is useful because it conserves memory. When the user returns to the page, the page is loaded again.

You can change this behavior by setting the [`NavigationCacheMode` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.navigationcachemode)on your page:

```
<Page 
   ...
   NavigationCacheMode="Required">
```

If you set `NavigationCacheMode` to `Enabled` or `Required`, the page will be cached and will be restored when user navigates back to it. The page's `Loaded` event will still be called, but you can just check if the data is already initialized or not either by checking the control directly or by checking a `bool` flag variable you set after initialization:

```
private void MainPage_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!initialized)
    {
        loadList();
        initialized = true;
    }
}
```

Difference between `Enabled` and `Required` is that `Enabled` honors the `CacheSize` setting on your `Frame`. Once there is more cached pages stored than the limit, the `Frame` will automatically remove the oldest one from memory. `Required` pages however don't count towards this limit and are never removed.

A slightly better alternative to this solution would be to use the MVVM design pattern. In this pattern data for your views are stored inside `ViewModel` classes and many MVVM frameworks maintain the `ViewModels` for the pages in your navigation stack in memory. This means that your page will be reloaded, but the data will be already available in the view model, so it will load fast. MVVM is the recommended pattern for developing UWP apps so I highly recommend you to try out either [Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism), [MvvmLight](http://www.mvvmlight.net/) or [MvvmCross](https://www.mvvmcross.com/).

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear yet detailed explanation! This saves my life!

Comment: Glad it helps :-). Happy coding!

Comment: How can I set the cache property for a content page? When I tried setting it like you showed it does not recognize the NavigationCacheMode property

Comment: @MartinZikmund Yes in Xamarin.Forms. I have a UWP and Android project, trying to keep content in entries etc. between navigation.

Comment: Xamarin.Forms uses a different navigational pattern than UWP - e.g. XF app runs all in one native UWP page, so ContentPage is just a XF concept. Unfortunately I don't know how to achieve such caching with XF ContentPage. I think a solution would be to ensure the ViewModel stays in memory and then just refuse it when navigating bac, but I am not sure if there is a way to preserve the UI elements as well

Comment: Thanks @MartinZikmund , I'll see if there is a question for this topic specific to XF. If not, I'll open a new one

Comment: Saved my life with one simple piece of XAML