# C# Navigating Between Pages Without losing Data

Tags: c#, uwp

One of my assignments is to pass data to another page which I understand. But how do I get the data to stay when I go back to the Page?  Can someone explain how this works.

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
       string userName;
       public MainPage()
     {

        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnPage2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2) ,  userName);
    }

    private void btnName_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        userName = Convert.ToString(txtname.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well can we see the page class too to understand what the variables are?

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48849603/732221). The answer there applies to this problem as well, however in your case you are especially focusing on the data part in question, so here you should pay special attention to the second part of the answer - using a `ViewModel` that will outlive the page itself would be the most beneficial solution. However using `NavigationCacheMode` will be sufficient as well, as the page class itself along with its fields will be preserved.

There is a third option available here, which is using `static` for the field you want to keep, or creating a `static` or singleton class that will hold the data. This however comes with a disadvantage when compared to the `ViewModel` solution as it does not easily allow having a single page multiple times in the navigation stack with different state data.