# C# Page can't reload back the previous page and the datagridview data is lost

Tags: c#, datagridview

Below is the button click handler to reload back the previous page, but it can't work secondly.

```
(First page)
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
            selectdata sl = new selectdata();
            sl.Show();
            Visible = false;
        }

(second Page)
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                List<CommonValue> CV = new List<CommonValue>();

                foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(item.Cells[0].Value))
                    {
                        CV.Add(new CommonValue
                        {    
                            Id = item.Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
                            Name = item.Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
                            description = item.Cells[3].Value.ToString(),
                            qty = item.Cells[4].Value.ToString(),
                            uom = item.Cells[5].Value.ToString(),
                            price = item.Cells[6].Value.ToString(),
                        });
                    }    
                }
                this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
                trdata tr = new trdata();
                tr.Values = CV;
                tr.Show();

                Visible = false; 
            }
```

this is the Program.cs

```
static void Main()
    {
     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
     Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
     Form1 f1 = new Form1();
     Form2 s1 = new Form2();
     if (f1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        string result = s1.yourDesiredResult;
        Application.Run(s1);
       }
        else
        {
         Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

**Page Screenshots:**

- https://ibb.co/g9hT0n8
- https://ibb.co/cgvXBZT
- https://ibb.co/2FPxMS2
- https://ibb.co/3R5qyj9

Comment: https://ibb.co/g9hT0n8
https://ibb.co/cgvXBZT
https://ibb.co/2FPxMS2
https://ibb.co/3R5qyj9

Comment: this is the page pic

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49112925/c-sharp-navigating-between-pages-without-losing-data

Comment: i m using window form

Comment: is window form can use NavigationCacheMode?